# TIdhttp HTTPS handshake Failed

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am using Indy 10 to connect to a SOAP Web Service.  When I run the code with Fiddler running I find the webserver is not negotiating our Handshake.  I have attached a screen shot of the Fiddler Inspectors.

We have been able to successfully connect to the server using the shareware application "SoapUI".  I have attached a screen shot of the inspectors when using SoapUI.

One thing I notice is SoapUI is using a different version of SSL/TLS.  How do I configure Indy to use the same version?

Any other insight as to why my call is failing?

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  idhttp: TIdhttp;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Params   : TStringStream;
begin
    idhttp := TIdhttp.Create(nil);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create(nil);
    idhttp.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
    idhttp.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888 ;
    idhttp.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    idhttp.Request.CharSet:='utf-8';
    idhttp.request.connection := 'keep-alive';
    idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Content-Type','text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('SOAPAction','"http://ws.nemsis.org/SubmitData"');
    idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Host','nemsis.org:443');
    idhttp.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    idhttp.request.username := 'xxxxx';
    idhttp.request.password := 'yyyyy';
    with IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 do begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
      SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
    end;
    with IdHTTP do begin
      IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
    end;
    Params := TStringStream.Create(filetostring(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))+'\sample.xml'));
    idhttp.Post('https://nemsis.org:443/NemsisV3Validator4/NemsisWsService',Params);
end;
```

Failed Call:
[image]

Successful Call using SoapUI:
[image]

Comment: "*How do I configure Indy to use the same version?*" - you already are. But which version of the OpenSSL DLLs are you using? Indy silently falls back to TLS 1.0 if it can't access the functions for TLS 1.1 or 1.2.

Comment: I recently openssl-0.9.8r-x64_86-win64-rev2.zip from the Fulgan site.  I copied the two dlls to the path where the exe lives.  They are versioni 0.9.8.18.  Is it good enough to copy the files to the path where the exe lives?  Or do they need to be properly installed?

Comment: Putting the DLLs in the app's folder is fine. But 0.9.8 is extremely old, which is why TLS 1.2 is not working. You should be using 1.0.2p instead

Comment: Now using 1.0.2p; however it is not using TLS 1.2; Fiddler is showing this: Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)

Comment: There are 2 version numbers in `ClientHello`: 1) the `TLSPlaintext` version in which the message itself is encoded (can be *any* `3.x` value in `ClientHello`, since the client doesn't know the server's supported versions until `ServerHello` is received); and 2) the highest `client_version` that the client is requesting. A client could send a `ClientHello` in TLS 1.0 format, but request TLS 1.2 for subsequent messaging. That is perfectly acceptable. It is not clear which version number Fiddler is displaying. I suspect the message encoding version, not the requested version.

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark instead to see the complete messages?  It would show all of the details.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that the two `ClientHello` messages you show are using different TLS extensions.  Most importantly, the "successful" `ClientHello` has the `server_name` extension, whereas the "failed" `ClientHello` does not.  Many modern TLS 1.2 servers require that extension and will fail a handshake without it.  Which exact version of Indy are you using?  Make sure you are using an up-to-date version that enables the `server_name` extension when using TLS.

Comment: No - not using Wire Shark.  I have now tried on Berlin Delphi (Indy version: 10.6.2.5341) and also Delphi 2007 (Indy Version:10.6.1.5235)

Comment: I will try to add the "server_name" extension... researching that now...  but if you could tell me that would be great!

Comment: Got the server_name extension added (        IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.OnStatusInfoEx := DoStatusInfoEx;).  Still does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180831/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-m-schenkel).